# Установка связей между графическими элементами в QT

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

Пишу программу для расчета комбинационных схем.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какими средствами Qt( C++) можно реализовать установку связей между элементами подобную matlab simulink.Чтобы как здесь стрелочкой соединять.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему вы можете использовать [QGraphicsLineItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslineitem.html). [Вот пример](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) того, что вы хотите.